# mostrar resultado de consulta

Tags: php, html, mysql

Necesito mostrar en una tabla de dos columnas en html una consulta de una base de datos. Lo he hecho así, pero no me sale:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Poblacion</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $sql3='SELECT city.Name,city.Population FROM city as city INNER JOIN country AS country ON city.CountryCode=country.Code
            WHERE (country.Region="'.$region.'") AND (country.Name="'.$name.'")';
        $resultado3=$db->query($sql3);
        echo $region;
        echo $name;
        echo "<br>";
        while($row=$resultado3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            print_r ($row);
            echo "<br>";
            //echo '<tr><td>'.$row[0].'</td><td>'.$row[1].'</td></tr>';
        }
    ?>
    </table>
```

Me aparece esto, pero así no lo quiero:

> Array ( [Name] => Oranjestad [Population] => 29034 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas accesar los nombres de las columnas asi:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Poblacion</th>
</tr>
<?php
    $sql3='SELECT city.Name,city.Population FROM city as city INNER JOIN country AS country ON city.CountryCode=country.Code
        WHERE (country.Region="'.$region.'") AND (country.Name="'.$name.'")';
    $resultado3=$db->query($sql3);
    echo $region;
    echo $name;

    while($row=$resultado3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .  $row['Name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .  $row['Population'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";           
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado perfectamente.